# How to configure zsh with oh-my-zsh to keep git history visible after pressing "q"?

Tags: terminal, git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use zsh with oh-my-zsh on a daily basis but there is a small thing that bothers me. If I use `git log` or any other similar command then the output occupies full terminal window. After pressing <kbd>q</kbd> the output is cleared and I'm back to my prompt.

I'd like the output to remain on screen. What could I configure to achieve this?

A picture is worth a thousand words, so here's a gif of the current behavior:

[image]

And here's my .zshrc:

```
plugins=(
  gitfast docker osx web-search cp
)
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See what you have configured under core.pager.  You probably have it set to `less` without the `-X` flag set. Having that flag set will keep `less` from clearing the screen upon exit.

If that's the case, go to `~/.gitconfig` and edit `pager` under the `[core]` section.  I have mine set to `-FRSX`.

```
$ git config --get core.pager
less -FRSX
```

And for your convenience, this is from the `less` man page describing what each of those flags mean:

```
   -F or --quit-if-one-screen
          Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.

   -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
          Like -r, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are output in "raw" form.  Unlike -r, the screen appearance is maintained correctly in most cases.  ANSI "color" escape sequences are sequences of the form:

               ESC [ ... m

          where  the "..." is zero or more color specification characters For the purpose of keeping track of screen appearance, ANSI color escape sequences are assumed to not move the cursor.  You can make less think that characters other than "m" can end ANSI
          color escape sequences by setting the environment variable LESSANSIENDCHARS to the list of characters which can end a color escape sequence.  And you can make less think that characters other than the standard ones may appear between the ESC and the m
          by setting the environment variable LESSANSIMIDCHARS to the list of characters which can appear.

   -S or --chop-long-lines
          Causes lines longer than the screen width to be chopped (truncated) rather than wrapped.  That is, the portion of a long line that does not fit in the screen width is not shown.  The default is to wrap long lines; that is, display the remainder on the
          next line.

   -X or --no-init
          Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal.  This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen.
```

Answer (score 3):

By default and depending on your `~/.gitconfig` file git will use a pager for the output of `git log` and `git diff` etc.

To disable this behavior you can use the `--no-pager` option:

```
git --no-pager log
```

Comment: Thank you, this is **really useful**, but actually it displays all history at once instead of the solution provided by @junior-citizen

Answer (score 0):

Just follow below instructions.

1. Just type `vi ~/.gitconfig` in your terminal.
2. Paste `LESS="-F -X $LESS"` line.
3. Press `:wq` and enter.
4. Restart your terminal.